# Creating Time picker in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datetime, lightning-design-system, time

Can Anyone please help me with creating time picker in lightning ?
There is a component

```
ui:inputDateTime
```

for having time & date picker both at the same time and there is a single component for date

```
ui:inputDate
```

for having input date field, but I could not found any time picker for taking input of time from user, I don't want to use the HTML5 tags and other JS library. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Check out lightningstrike.io. I think they have a time component

Comment: @Eric Thanks, But there is only DatePicker I have already check it.

Comment: why don't you want to use html5 tags?